# ¿Como validar el formato de la hora en el formato de 12 hrs?

Tags: php, html

me gustaría saber como valido si la hora ingresada por el usuario tiene el formato correcto y que no haya ingresado caracteres no deseados, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo con una expresion regular y la funcion `preg_match()`:
formato de 12 horas:

```
preg_match("/^(?:1[012]|0[0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/", $hours);
```

formato de 24 horas:

```
preg_match("/^(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]$/", $hours);
```